# How to convert excel file to a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python

I have a large Excel file, and I want to convert it into a list of tuples.

Excel file:

```
      Programming    Math
Alex     95          100
Mike     99           80
```

Desired output:

```
[('Alex', 'Programming', 95), ('Alex', 'Math', 100), ..]
```

Comment: @SuperShoot Excuse me, but these proposed duplicates have nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: too right @coldspeed, I'll remove.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe we can help you starting from something you've coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with a list comprehension (pandas should read the names into the index if your file looks like the one in the question).

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('./xls-to-tuples.xlsx')
[(ix, k, v) for ix, row in data.iterrows() for k, v in row.items()]

[('Alex', 'Programming', 95),
 ('Alex', 'Maths', 100),
 ('Mike', 'Programming', 99),
 ('Mike', 'Maths', 80)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the names are in an index you will need to reset that so they are included. To get tuples use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) but keep the new `index` Series using `id_vars` (or whatever the names Series is called); then use [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), as so:

```
      Programming  Math
Alex           95   100
Mike           99    80

df.reset_index()
  index  Programming  Math
0  Alex           95   100
1  Mike           99    80

df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index')
  index     variable  value
0  Alex  Programming     95
1  Mike  Programming     99
2  Alex         Math    100
3  Mike         Math     80

df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').values
array([['Alex', 'Programming', 95],
       ['Mike', 'Programming', 99],
       ['Alex', 'Math', 100],
       ['Mike', 'Math', 80]], dtype=object)
```

Or, all in a one line:

```
[tuple(v) for v in df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').values]
[('Alex', 'Programming', 95), 
 ('Mike', 'Programming', 99), 
 ('Alex', 'Math', 100), 
 ('Mike', 'Math', 80)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's with `stack` and `itertuples`:

```
tuples = list(map(tuple, df.stack().reset_index().itertuples(index=False)))
```

Or,

```
tuples = list(map(tuple, df.stack().reset_index().values))
```

```
print(tuples)
[('Alex', 'Programming', 95),
 ('Alex', 'Math', 100),
 ('Mike', 'Programming', 99),
 ('Mike', 'Math', 80)]
```